# Inclusion of redirected HTTP requests in the scripts

Tags: jmeter

My recoded script has the following HTTP requests:

Request-A (with a comment: Detected the start of a redirect chain)
Request-B (with a comment: Detected the start of a redirect chain)
Request-C (disabled but with a comment: Detected the start of a redirect chain)
Request-D

When the script was run after adding the relevant correlations, Request-A is re-directed to all the subsequent requests (B, C & D).

1. In this case, do I need to include requests B, C & D or just leave them out and include only the first request (A)?
2. Should the disabled steps in the recording be omitted in the script? Why some of the steps/requests are disabled in the recording?

Thanks
N

Answer (score 0):

1. Your JMeter test must represent [the real user using the real browser with 100% accuracy](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser). So you shouldn't ask random people in the Internet, you need to ensure that JMeter sends the same requests as the browser when you're executing your test scenario steps. It can be done using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

   My expectation is that you need to leave only "main" sampler and let it redirect automatically
2. As per [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder proxy source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/proxy/ProxyControl.java#L612) this is exactly the case when recorded HTTP requests are marked as disabled so you should rather let JMeter follow redirects than create duplicate requests

   ```
   if (urlAsString.equals(LAST_REDIRECT)) { // the url matches the last redirect
       sampler.setEnabled(false);
       sampler.setComment("Detected a redirect from the previous sample");
   } else { /
   ```